# Cassandra DB - sub column query

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I am novice to Cassandra db and trying to query the sub column First Name from the below table but failing miserably. I am able to query the direct column name but not the sub one under it.

**CALLER INFO Table structure is below** :

```
1. Unique ID
2. CustomerInfo
        {First Name,
        Middle Name,
        Last Name,
        Date of Birth,
        Sex}
```

Please let me know the query to retrieve the details of First Name , DOB etc.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, the [Cassandra 2.1 docs have an example](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html) for this.  Based on the information you have provided, I'll create a user defined type (UDT):

```
 aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TYPE info (
             ... firstName TEXT,
             ... middleName TEXT,
             ... lastName TEXT,
             ... dob TEXT,
             ... sex TEXT);
```

Then I'll create a table called `callerInfo`:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE callerInfo (
             ... customerID UUID,
             ... customerInfo frozen<info>,
             ... PRIMARY KEY customerID);
```

Next I'll create a secondary index on `customerInfo`:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE INDEX cinfo_idx ON callerInfo (customerInfo);
```

Now I'll try to query just on `lastName`:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM callerInfo WHERE customerInfo={lastName:'Scott'};

(0 rows)
```

**Why doesn't that work?**  Because with the current implementation of secondary indexes on UDTs, I have to specify conditions for *all of the components*.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM callerInfo WHERE 
    customerInfo={firstName:'Michael', middlename:'Gary', lastname:'Scott', dob:'1964/03/15', sex:'M'};

 customerid                           | customerinfo
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 f1dea08f-5870-402d-82e1-ee9e215e0294 | {firstname: 'Michael', middlename: 'Gary', lastname: 'Scott', dob: '1964/03/15', sex: 'M'}

(1 rows)
```

So that may (or may not) work for your use case.  Honestly though, I would *not* use this approach for two reasons.

1. Secondary indexes are known to not perform well at-scale...and that's for a non-collection/UDT column.  I can only imagine that a secondary index on a UDT would perform worse.
2. You can *very* easily model this in Cassandra *without* having to use a UDT or a secondary index.

Since you identified that you need to query your customers by last name, I would design a table to specifically serve that query:

```
CREATE TABLE callerInfoByLastName (
  lastName TEXT,
  firstName TEXT,
  middleName TEXT,
  customerID UUID,
  dob TEXT,
  sex TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((lastName),firstName,middleName,customerID));
```

Now you can query by `lastName`, and have your data ordered by `firstName` and `middleName` (within each `lastName`).  `customerID` is added to the PK to ensure uniqueness (in the event that you have to different people with the same name).  For date of birth (dob) I would create a new, similar query table, and duplicate your data there as well.